# Networking: fallback failed requests to another network interface

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, routing, cntlm

I'm on a linux workstation behind a microsoft proxy server so I've installed cntlm to handle proxy authentication.

Now I want to add some more complexity; I want failed requests to use another network interface. Is this possible?
To clarify my request:

- Start request from a client (browser, package manager, ecc...) through cntlm local proxy -> *eth0* -> network proxy
- If the request is succesful: ok, end of the workflow
- Otherwise: retry the request using *eth1* without passing through cntlm

Another acceptable solution is to use specific routes for intersted IPs, I tried this solution but I was not able to make it work. Requests still pass through cntlm, failing because parent proxy doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

using an additional network adapter do not have anything to do with cntlm.
You have to configure a proper routing, add a secondary route with a higher distance.
I cannot suggest you the right one, this depends on the ip address and the network you use.

Comment: ryder, thank you for the response. Cntlm gets on the way when I try to use the network interface connected to the "open" network not behind proxy. Anyway your answer suggested me a possible solution to my problem. Thank you again